# Free ways to extract files from encrypted iPhone backup

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, encryption

Does anyone knows any free (as in really free and not limited in any way) solution to extract files (messages, call history etc) from an encrypted iPhone backup?

I know the password, so this is not a question about decryption or brute-forcing the backup or something like that. The backup was created on my Windows 10 64-bit PC.

I do know, there are tons of apps on the internet to do this, but they all cost money or are limited in some way, and I'm not interested in any of these so-called "free" apps, where you can only extract like 3 files, and then you need to buy a license to extract the rest...

Hope anyone knows a solution. Thank you very much.

PS: There is no way for me to create an unencrypted backup, since the "Encrypt local backup" checkbox is greyed out in iTunes... :-(

Comment: iMazing is a whole $35, skip whatever your vice is one weekend and buy a copy.

Comment: I use the paid app iExplorer. It does the job. If you really need the data, spend the money. I've been using it for years. _Disclaimer: Satisfied user of iExplorer - no financial or other compensation from Macroplant LLC._

Answer (score 3):

In case you are comfortable with installing a few Python packages and using the Python interpreter, jsharkey13's [iphone_backup_decrypt package](https://github.com/jsharkey13/iphone_backup_decrypt) on github worked perfectly for me. It can decrypt backups and extract any files.

From within my Mac's Terminal app, I installed the dependencies and package code from github using `pip`, exactly as described in the install instructions. Then ran the `python` interpreter and copy-pasted the example code line by line into it (you'll have to set the `passphrase` variable to your actual passphrase rather than "..."). And in no time I got all my photos (and other files) out!

I would recommend using the [Anaconda Python](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) distribution (or, to save some disk space, the much smaller [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) variant) to [create and activate a fresh virtual environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) for installing these packages, just to keep them separate from the Python installation that comes with MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
imactoolsDOTcom - no multi image export
reincubateDOTcom - 4 photo max
imyfoneDOTcom - LIE IS NOT FREE
imazing 50 photo max
```

if your backup has no password then python script will be not working